# Newtonsoft deserialize multiple JSON files with cross references

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have two JSON files (that I can't change the format for) in the following format:

Main file -

```
[
   {
      "Name":"XYZ",
      "UnitReferenceId":1
   },
   {
      "Name":"ABC",
      "UnitReferenceId":2
   }
]
```

The lookup/reference JSON file -

```
[
   {
      "UnitReferenceId":1,
      "Units":[
         {
            "Unit":"mg",
            "Scale":1
         },
         {
            "Unit":"gm",
            "Scale":1000
         },
         {
            "Unit":"kg",
            "Scale":1000000
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "UnitReferenceId":2,
      "Units":[
         {
            "Unit":"mm",
            "Scale":1
         },
         {
            "Unit":"m",
            "Scale":1000
         },
         {
            "Unit":"km",
            "Scale":1000000
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How would I go about deserializing that into C# classes using Newtonsoft JSON into something like:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public UnitReference UnitReference { get; set; }
}

public class UnitReference
{
    public long UnitReferenceId { get; set; }
    public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}
public class Unit
{
    [JsonProperty("Unit")]
    public string UnitValue { get; set; }
    public long Scale { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by reading your two JSON files as follows:

1. First read the lookup/reference JSON file for `UnitReference` as a `List<UnitReference>`, then convert to a `Dictionary<long, UnitReference>` lookup table.
2. Next, read the main file using a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `Widget` that is passed the `Dictionary<long, UnitReference>` lookup table and can translate between `UnitReferenceId` and `UnitReference` during reading and writing.

Thus your classes would look like the following:

```
public class UnitReference
{
    readonly long unitReferenceId;

    public UnitReference(long unitReferenceId)
    {
        this.unitReferenceId = unitReferenceId;
    }

    public long UnitReferenceId { get { return unitReferenceId; } }

    public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
    [JsonProperty("Unit")]
    public string UnitValue { get; set; }
    public long Scale { get; set; }
}

public class Widget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UnitReference UnitReference { get; set; }
}
```

(My only modification was to make `UnitReferenceId` be read-only so that it safely could be used as a dictionary key.)

Then, define the following converter:

```
public class WidgetConverter : CustomPropertyConverterBase<Widget>
{
    readonly IDictionary<long, UnitReference> units;

    public WidgetConverter(IDictionary<long, UnitReference> units)
    {
        this.units = units;
    }

    protected override void ReadCustomProperties(JObject obj, Widget value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var id = (long?)obj.GetValue("UnitReferenceId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (id != null)
            value.UnitReference = units[id.Value];
    }

    protected override bool ShouldSerialize(JsonProperty property, object value)
    {
        if (property.UnderlyingName == nameof(Widget.UnitReference))
            return false;
        return base.ShouldSerialize(property, value);
    }

    protected override void WriteCustomProperties(JsonWriter writer, Widget value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value.UnitReference != null)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName("UnitReferenceId");
            writer.WriteValue(value.UnitReference.UnitReferenceId);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class CustomPropertyConverterBase<T> : JsonConverter where T : class
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        var value = existingValue as T ?? (T)contract.DefaultCreator();

        ReadCustomProperties(jObj, value, serializer);

        // Populate the remaining properties.
        using (var subReader = jObj.CreateReader())
        {
            serializer.Populate(subReader, value);
        }

        return value;
    }

    protected abstract void ReadCustomProperties(JObject obj, T value, JsonSerializer serializer);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in contract.Properties.Where(p => ShouldSerialize(p, value)))
        {
            var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
            if (propertyValue == null && serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
                continue;
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.PropertyName);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
        }
        WriteCustomProperties(writer, (T)value, serializer);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    protected virtual bool ShouldSerialize(JsonProperty property, object value)
    {
        return property.Readable && !property.Ignored && (property.ShouldSerialize == null || property.ShouldSerialize(value));
    }

    protected abstract void WriteCustomProperties(JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializer serializer);
}
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
var units = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UnitReference>>(unitsJsonString)
    .ToDictionary(u => u.UnitReferenceId);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new WidgetConverter(units) },
};
var widgets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Widget>>(widgetsJsonString, settings);
```

Notes:

- Here I am deserializing from JSON strings for demo purposes, but you can deserialize directly from your file(s) as shown in [*Deserialize JSON from a file*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm).
- The base class `CustomPropertyConverterBase<T>` for `WidgetConverter` automatically reads and writes all properties for the object being (de)serialized.  `WidgetConverter` then overrides this behavior for the `UnitReference` property only, avoiding the necessity to manually serialize all the remaining properties of `Widget`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M3SoJX).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for creating my classes quickly.  If you have to implement it in code, see [JSON C# Class Generator Project](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/).